# SQL Snowflake Queries in databricks in R

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

is there a way ho I can execute SQL queries on Snowflake database when using R databricks?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Spark connector for Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-databricks.html) that is already shipped as part of the Databricks runtime - configure it as described in the documentation - you need following information to access data:

- URL for your Snowflake account.
- Login name and password for the user who connects to the account.
- Default database and schema to use for the session after connecting.
- Default virtual warehouse to use for the session after connecting.

After that you'll able to access the data in Snowflake using the standard Spark API, like this:

```r
snow.df.sparkr <- SparkR::read.df(
  source = "snowflake", 
  sfUrl = "<snowflake-url>",
  sfUser = user,
  sfPassword = password,
  sfDatabase = "<snowflake-database>",
  sfSchema = "<snowflake-schema>",
  sfWarehouse = "<snowflake-cluster>",
  dbtable = "iris"
)
```

[Databrick's documentation on Snowflake](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/snowflake.html) includes full notebooks in different languages, including R.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Alex, actualy this is what I was looking for:

```r
snow.df.sparkr <- SparkR::read.df(
  source = "snowflake", 
  sfUrl = "<snowflake-url>",
  sfUser = user,
  sfPassword = password,
  sfDatabase = "<snowflake-database>",
  sfSchema = "<snowflake-schema>",
  sfWarehouse = "<snowflake-cluster>",
  query= "select * from iris" ##query specification
)
```