# How to read a table from snowflake using R scripting in Databricks

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks, sparkr

I am trying to read data from snowflake to Databricks using R scripting. Can anyone please help how to write. I could not find it in documentation.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65777941/7798548) should be a good start.